# Containerized logic app not working when deployed to AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-logic-apps

We are trying to deploy a logic app as containerized workload in AKS. Following is our Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0.14492-appservice

ENV AzureWebJobsStorage=<StorageAccount connection string>
ENV AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT Development
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
ENV FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=true

COPY ./bin/release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ /home/site/wwwroot
```

Following is our deployment manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
  namespace: canary
  labels:
    app: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      containers:
        - name: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
          image: "image_link"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: AzureBlob_connectionString
              value: <connection_string>
            - name: AzureWebJobsStorage
              value: <connection_string>
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: sbx-acr-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
  namespace: canary
  labels:
    app: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http-pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
  selector:
    app: pfna-pgt-sf-pdfextract
```

Following is connections.json:

```
{
  "serviceProviderConnections": {
    "AzureBlob": {
      "parameterValues": {
        "connectionString": "@appsetting('AzureWebJobsStorage')"
      },
      "serviceProvider": {
        "id": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
      },
      "displayName": "localAzureBlob"
    }
  },
  "managedApiConnections": {}
}
```

Following is the host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "workflow": {
       "settings": {
          "Runtime.Backend.VariableOperation.MaximumStatelessVariableSize": "5000000"
       }
    }
 }
}
```

The image is running successfully in docker desktop but when deployed to AKS we are getting 'Function host is not running'.

Please help resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify WEBSITE_HOSTNAME as well (doesn't matter what it is, just needs to be specified)

That being said, as of today there is another issue that is causing the function host to not start (libadvapi32.dll).